# TensorFlow GPU, CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED on tf.one_hot()

Tags: tensorflow

I try to run tf.one_hot, get CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED error.  Here is the details:

Sample code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
idx_0 = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [None])
mask = tf.one_hot(idx_0, 3, axis=-1)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
a = sess.run([mask],feed_dict={idx_0:[0,1,2]})
print(a)
```

Expected result:

```
[array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]], dtype=float32)]
```

Actual result:

```
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_driver.cc:1177] could not synchronize on CUDA context: CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED :: No stack trace available
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_event.cc:49] Error polling for event status: failed to query event: CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED
F c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_util.cc:370] GPU sync failed
```

Config of the PC:

- TensorFlow 0.12.0-rc1
- Python 3.5
- CUDA 8.0
- cuDNN 5.1
- OS: Windows 10
- GPU: GeForce GTX 970

tf.one_hot run ok when running on Linux CPU, Linux GPU (GeForce GTX 660), Windows 10 CPU.  Not ok on the Windows 10 GPU.

On the Windows 10 GPU, tf.matmul, tf.reduce_mean, tf.reduce_sum are run ok.  But tf.one_hot is not ok.

Is that a bug, or I miss something?  Thanks.

(Edit 2016-12-16)

I have run the code on the same machine, in Xubuntu, GPU.  The code run fine.  So I think that is a problem in TensorFlow-Windows.

Answer (score 4):

Also leaving a comment as an answer, in my case because I don't have enough reputation to comment.

Have you reported this as a bug on GitHub? I too can confirm this behaviour with the same Tensorflow/OS/Graphics Card/etc

Just moving the tf.one_hot() to the CPU solves the issue for me, i.e. something like

`with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    b = tf.one_hot(a, 123)`

Comment: Thanks. Posted to https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6783 .

Answer (score 0):

I am commenting as an 'answer' as my feedback is too detailed as a comment.

I ran your sample and got these results:

```
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:906] DMA: 0 
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:916] 0:   Y 
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 745, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_event.cc:49] Error polling for event status: failed to query event: CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED
F c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_event_mgr.cc:198] Unexpected Event status: 1
```

My configuration:

- TensorFlow 0.12.0-rc1 for GPU
- Python 3.5.2/Anaconda 4.2.0
- CUDA 8.0
- cuDNN 5.1
- OS: Windows 10
- GPU: GeForce GTX 745 (OEM)

I have other code that produces the above errors.  Running it on another computer with a similar configuration but with the TensorFlow 0.12.0-rc1 for CPU only release runs fine.  I suggest you test your code with that version of TensorFlow.